# How do I print a Node.js Buffer as binary?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Buffer object like

```js
<Buffer FF 00>
```

How do I print it as actual 1's and 0's, like this

```
11111111 00000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use .map and a function that will convert each byte to its binary representation. Using .join() will then give us the combined binary string. If you just want an array as output you can omit the .join() call.

```
function byteToBinaryString(s) {
    return s.toString(2).padStart(8, '0');
}

const buffer = Buffer.from('abcd');
console.log([...buffer].map(byteToBinaryString).join(" "));
```

For this example we'll see an output like so:

```
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function toBinaryString (buf) {
  let result = []
  for (let b of buf) {
    result.push(b.toString(2).padStart(8, '0'))
  }
  return result.join(' ')
}
```

Usage:

```
> toBinaryString(Buffer.from('test'))
'01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100'
```